# I can´t insert annotations or code inside package-info,java in android studio

Tags: android, jaxb, package-info

I made jaxb working inside my android project but for jaxb purposes i need to use @xmlschema and @xmlns inside porject-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "espacio_person",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "espacio_person", prefix = "ep"),
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "espacio_job", prefix = "ej")
        })
package pe.net.tci.jpaez.jaxbxmltest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

The problem is when I get the APK in debug mode or just building the project inside this package-file.java i only get the package name:

```
package pe.net.tci.jpaez.jaxbxmltest;
```

I want to know what I have to do to make the code inside the package-info files.

Best regards

Comment: Does JAXB work on Android?

Comment: Do you have the needed `import`statements (after the `package` statement)?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry for not putting these codes. I edited my questions

I must say that i implemented jars customized for android and I have JAXB worked. I don´t have problem with the xml generation, my problem is on the elements that don't have namespace and prefixes because of the package-info.

Comment: You can also specify namespaces directly in `@XmlElement` etc. annotations.

Comment: I know but, I am using a jar project (ph-ubl) and this project uses package-info. That's why I want to use this jar with these package-info working.